# Get personal credit report data via online api

Tags: api

I am adding the ability for users of my web app to get credit reports of people applying to them.  I am looking for a service that charges per credit report request - ideally, not a monthly fee.  What options exist that provide an online api for retrieving personal credit reports?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SmartMove from TransUnion](http://www.mysmartmove.com/) does the trick.  They have white label and integration options available.

Comment: they charge $25 +$5 per run, is there a cheaper service out there? i'm working on something that requires credit report. It won't generate as much revenue as apartment leasing, so $25 per run would kill my margins. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Talked to a TransUnion rep today and it depends on the company but in my case (a financial services website for a client) there's a $225 startup fee, $50/month subscription fee and a charge of $3.5 per credit report pulled through their API.

Comment: Do you have a link to more details about using their api?

Comment: I don't unfortunately - the info was from an email and a phone call with a TransUnion rep back in June.